# How can I get a list of folders/subfolders that DOES NOT contain a specific type of file?

Tags: windows, powershell

For example, I wanted to print a list of folders which contain an `.html` file. Correct me if I am wrong, but this worked for me:

```
dir /S *.html > C:\Users\PC\Desktop\with-html.txt
```

Now I would like to find the folders which do not contain .html files.

How do I go about that?

**EDIT:**

The folders are structured in a way that only the child folders (last subfolder) have any kind of files. I would like to get a list of directories to those subfolders. So the above command line is giving me:

```
C:\...\ml\regression\lasso-regression
C:\...\ml\regression\linear-regression
```

There is not output just `C:\...\ml` or `C:\...\ml\regression`.

The folder structure looks like this:

- C:\...\ml

  - classification
  - regression

    - lasso-regression
    - linear-regression

There are about 10 folders in folder `ml` and no files. There are again about 10 folders in second folder level where `C:\...\ml\regression\linear-regression` contains an HTML file while `C:\...\ml\regression\lasso-regression` does not contain a file with file extension `.html`. Only the folders in last level of the folders tree have files at all.

I'd be grateful getting just the list of the last folders in folders tree not containing a file with file extension `.html`.

I basically output the above command line into a `.csv` file, filtered it with MS Excel, and have now a list of folders with `.html` file(s). I'm basically working with R-markdown files, and it'll be a status report, the folders list with .html files is what I have completed already. So in need now only the opposite folders list.

Comment: The posted command line searches recursive for file system entries (files and directories and reparse points) matching the wildcard pattern `*.html` and outputs all found with full path. So you get with this command line most likely a list of HTML __files__ with full qualified file names, but not a list of directories containing HTML files. You would also get directory names if there are directories with a name ending with `.html`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not difficult using PowerShell.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory |
    ForEach-Object {
        if ((Get-ChildItem -File -Path $_.FullName -Filter '*.html').Length -eq 0) { $_.FullName }
    }
```

If you must run this in a .bat file script, the following might be used.

```
@powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory |" ^
        "ForEach-Object {" ^
            "if ((Get-ChildItem -File -Path $_.FullName -Filter '*.html').Length -eq 0) { $_.FullName }" ^
        "}"
```